# Jquery append function: Expected ')' error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am making an ajax request in my php file, and the request is returning with correct value. But when I try to use append function in jquery it returns and erro in the console.

```
$.ajax({
                url:"ajax.php",
                type:"POST",
                success:function(msg){
                    $("#loadMoreButton").hide();
                    alert(msg.length);
                    $.each(msg, function(index){

                        $(".blog-masonry").append("<div class='post-masonry col-md-4 col-sm-6'> <div class='blog-thumb'> <img src='" + msg[index].image +"' alt=""> <div class='overlay-b'> <div class='overlay-inner'> <a href='#' class='fa fa-link'></a> </div></div></div><div class='blog-body'> <div class='box-content'><h3 class='post-title'><a href='" + msg[index].external_link +"' target='_blank'>" + msg[index].title + "</a></h3><span class='blog-meta'>" + msg[index].date_pub + "</span><p>"+ msg[index].Content +"</p></div></div></div>");

                    });
                    $("#loadMoreButton").show();
                },
                dataType:"json",
                data: {"from": ("" + id), "cat" : "<?php echo $_GET['category']; ?>"}
            });
```

The error says `SyntaxError: Expected token ')'` in the line where I try to append the html.

I'm not sure what is missing here?

Comment: Error is self-explanatory, just fix your syntax. Use proper IDE if it's not clear for you where. You have `alt=""` and it needs to be quoted: `alt=\"\"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `alt = ""` to `alt=''`

```
$(".blog-masonry").append("<div class='post-masonry col-md-4 col-sm-6'> <div class='blog-thumb'> <img src='" + msg[index].image +"' alt=''> <div class='overlay-b'> <div class='overlay-inner'> <a href='#' class='fa fa-link'></a> </div></div></div><div class='blog-body'> <div class='box-content'><h3 class='post-title'><a href='" + msg[index].external_link +"' target='_blank'>" + msg[index].title + "</a></h3><span class='blog-meta'>" + msg[index].date_pub + "</span><p>"+ msg[index].Content +"</p></div></div></div>");
```

Or you can use `escape character` (as mentioned in the comment)

`alt=\"\"`

The `backslash` is used as a marker character to tell the compiler/interpreter that the next character has some special meaning.